# Where is the select function?

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls

I want to see the code of `select` , So I find `<sys/select.h>`.
But I only get `extern int select (...);`

So my question is : where the really `select` function is.

I use SUSE by the way.

Comment: You are right it is in `<sys/select.h` What is your error?

Comment: The source code isn't in `sys/select.h`.

Comment: Wakeup, little SUSE, wakeup!

Comment: @jxh ? what's happened!

Comment: I should have included a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CByPkTZtnzU).

Comment: @jxh Thanks for your link.Since I lived in China , Youtube  is unavailable ~  pity~

Comment: @LidongGuo Learning how to cross over the wall is Lesson 101 for Chinese programmers :)

Comment: @YuHao Is it good to cross over the wall in company's computer?